# How to limit data size in php?

Tags: php

I am getting text content from web page as below.
Some time data in the `$text` is so large that I can not directly push it to my program.

so is there any way by which I can limit data content in `$text`. Something like 1028 bytes or any particular figure

```
<?php
//sent has value "http://www.paulgraham.com/herd.html"
$url=$_POST['sent'];
$text = file_get_contents($url);
$text=escapeshellarg(strip_tags($text));
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP `file_get_content` has several parameters, one of them is data size to read

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Ex:

```
 file_get_contents ( 'http://www.test.com/', false, NULL, -1, 200)
```

Otherwise, you can use cURL, that has more options.

Comment: thanks, I checked documentation. But when I use `$text = file_get_contents($url,false,NULL,0,2000);` rather taking 0 to 2000 characters it takes only first `Investor Herd Dynamics ` of the url content. Infact for 1200,1500, 2000 all limit it gives same result!

Comment: As I can see from source of your file, there are plenty of HTML entities in code, that will have size of 2000 characters. So, if you remove them, you will get only what you see.

Comment: Ok, I got. After performing `file_get_contents` without limit. and then is there any way to limit the data for particular range?

Comment: Other then substr if any!

Answer (score 3):

you can used inbuilt php substring function.

or

there are 5 parameter for lenght in file_get_contents(path,include_path,context,start,max_length)

[Check Example#3](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

// Read 14 characters starting from the 21st character

```
$section = file_get_contents('./people.txt', NULL, NULL, 20, 14);
```

var_dump($section);

Comment: thanks, I checked documentation. But when I use `$text = file_get_contents($url,false,NULL,0,2000);` rather taking 0 to 2000 characters it takes only first `Investor Herd Dynamics ` of the url content. Infact for 1200,1500, 2000 all limit it gives same result!

Comment: then used substring function

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to limit the length if you want:

```
<?php
//sent has value "http://www.paulgraham.com/herd.html"
$url=$_POST['sent'];
$text = file_get_contents($url);
$shortText= substr($text, 1024);
$shortText=escapeshellarg(strip_tags($shortText));
?>
```

Comment: @Flueffeh: thanks, but it does not limit it to size. When I printed it, It shows actual full text only. Here is my code `<?php
//sent has value "http://www.paulgraham.com/herd.html"
$url=$_POST['sent'];
$text = file_get_contents($url);
$shortText= substr($text, 900);
$shortText=escapeshellarg(strip_tags($shortText));
$test = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]+/", " ", html_entity_decode($shortText));
echo $test;
?>`